# SQL - Split string with multiple delimiters into multiple rows and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I am trying to split a string in SQL with the following format:
`'John, Mark, Peter|23, 32, 45'`.

The idea is to have all the names in the first columns and the ages in the second column.

[image]

The query should be "dynamic", the string can have several records depending on user entries.

Does anyone know how to this, and if possible without SQL functions? I have tried the cross apply approach but I wasn't able to make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Will have to split each entity first, then each value with a row number to match them afterwards. There are countless string split functions out there to search. If on SQL Server 2016+ you can use String_Split() to separate entities (but without row number).

Comment: Don't just add `sqlite3` to the tags without explaining why (it's unlikely people won't read the comments on my answer when they read your question). The `sqlite3` and `sql-server` conflict on their own. Explain your requirements in full.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). Why? Because his solution provides the **ordinal position** of the item. Ordinal Position something that many others functions, including Microsoft's own `STRING_SPLIT`, does not provide. It's going to be vitally important for getting this to work correctly.

Once you have that, the solution becomes fairly simple:

```
DECLARE @NameAges varchar(8000) = 'John, Mark, Peter|23, 32, 45';

WITH Splits AS (
    SELECT S1.ItemNumber AS PipeNumber,
           S2.ItemNumber AS CommaNumber,
           S2.Item
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (REPLACE(@NameAges,' ',''), '|') S1 --As you have spaces between the delimiters I've removed these. Be CAREFUL with that
         CROSS APPLY DelimitedSplit8K (S1.item, ',') S2)
SELECT S1.Item AS [Name], 
       S2.Item AS Age
FROM Splits S1
     JOIN Splits S2 ON S1.CommaNumber = S2.CommaNumber
                   AND S2.PipeNumber = 2
WHERE S1.PipeNumber = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you Larnu. I don't think that will work for me. It might work in SQL Server, but I'm concerned I will have to use other engines like Access SQL or SQLite. That's why I'm trying to avoid functions. Sorry about that

Comment: @FlavioJustino Different RDBMS will require different solutions; they are all different. The question you have asked here is only about SQL Server; if you have other RDBMS's you need a solution for, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49794387/edit) your question to actually reflect your requirement and tag the relevant RDBMS('s). you aren't going to get a "one size fits all" solution,as that is impossible.